# Why does Psycopg provide `cursor`'s methods (`copy_to()`, `copy_from()`), instead of calling `cursor.execute()` to send a `COPY` command?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

From http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from

> Psycopg `cursor` objects provide an interface (`copy_to()`, `copy_from()`, `copy_expert()`) to the efficient PostgreSQL `COPY` command to move data from files to tables and back.
>   Currently  no  adaptation  is  provided  between  Python  and  PostgreSQL  types  on `COPY`:
>   the file can be any Python file-like object but its format must be in the format accepted by
>   PostgreSQL `COPY` command (data format, escaped characters, etc).

`cursor.execute()` can send a command as a string to PostgreSQL server to execute. So why does Psycopg   provide `cursor`'s methods  (`copy_to()`, `copy_from()`, `copy_expert()`),  instead of calling `cursor.execute()` to send a `COPY` command as a string to PostgreSQL server to execute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a COPY command naming a file using [`execute()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15), and pass the filename using placeholders, but since it requires database superuser privileges, because it can read/write all files the server has access to, *it's usually better to avoid it*.

I suppose the special methods exist for the COPY commands using STDIN and STDOUT for receiving and sending data, since [`execute()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) as specified in the [DBAPI 2 spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) does not support such.

Also [`copy_expert()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert) does support sending a custom COPY command, while using STDIN and STDOUT. It's handy for dealing with CSV, for example.

Comment: Thanks. Why "since it requires database superuser privileges, it's usually better to avoid it"? Do  the special methods exist for the COPY commands   also have the same limitation?

Comment: They don't, since they use the standard input and output. It is then the client's reponsibility to be able to read the files. I'll quote the docs on why superuser is required, if directly copying from a named file: "COPY naming a file or command is only allowed to database superusers, since it allows reading or writing any file that the server has privileges to access." In other words you could overwrite for example configuration files and the like.

Comment: Thanks. When I execute() a COPY string, how shall I make it have the superuser privilleges?

Comment: If my Psycopg program connects to PostgreSQL server, using a user which is not superuser, is it correct that execute() a COPY string can't write or read any file?

Comment: Yes, for a good reason. Just use the provided specialized methods, if at all possible.